# Sort an array of multiple items

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a swift file where I defined the following array:

```
import Foundation

struct Squadre: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let stagione: String
    let squadra: String
    let vinte: Int
    let pareggiate: Int
    let perse: Int
    let golfatti: Int
    let golsubiti: Int
    let diffreti: Int
    let punti: Int
    let punteggio: Double
    
    init(stagione: String, squadra: String, vinte: Int, pareggiate: Int, perse: Int, golfatti: Int, golsubiti: Int, diffreti: Int, punti: Int, punteggio: Double) {
        self.stagione = stagione
        self.squadra = squadra
        self.vinte = vinte
        self.pareggiate = pareggiate
        self.perse = perse
        self.golfatti = golfatti
        self.golsubiti = golsubiti
        self.diffreti = golfatti - golsubiti
        self.punti = (vinte * 3) + (pareggiate)
        self.punteggio = Double(punti + (golfatti / 100) + (diffreti / 1000))
    }
    
    
    static func test() -> [Squadre] {
        [ Squadre(stagione: "2023/2024", squadra: "Castello", vinte: 10, pareggiate: 7, perse: 4, golfatti: 34, golsubiti: 27, diffreti: 7, punti: 37, punteggio: 37.347),
          Squadre(stagione: "2023/2024", squadra: "Sole", vinte: 10, pareggiate: 7, perse: 4, golfatti: 34, golsubiti: 28, diffreti: 6, punti: 37, punteggio: 37.346),
          Squadre(stagione: "2023/2024", squadra: "Spina", vinte: 11, pareggiate: 6, perse: 4, golfatti: 34, golsubiti: 27, diffreti: 7, punti: 39, punteggio: 39.347)]
    }    
}
```

Now, I have a view where I'm using this:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var squadre: [Squadre] = Squadre.test()
```

I'd like then to use this data into a List object, but I would like to have them ordered by "punteggio" so that the first item shown is "Spina".

I'm trying to use the sorting in the following way:

```
var squadreSort = squadre.sort(using: [
        KeyPathComparator(\.punteggio, order: .forward)])
```

but without getting any result.

Could you please help me?

Thanks,
A.

Comment: Hey Andrew, welcome to the site. "but without getting any result." Surely you're getting _some_ kind of result (just perhaps not the one you're looking for). What are you seeing, exactly?

Comment: `sort`sorts the collection in place [docu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/sort()). You need `sorted` [docu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/words-swift.struct/sorted()/).

Comment: You need sorted and .reverse to have Spina first.

Comment: @Marcy Rather than sorting `order: .forward` and then reversing, it would be better to just sort with `order: .reverse`

Comment: @Alexander yes. Are use suggesting something other than this: var squadreSort = squadre.sorted(using: [
   KeyPathComparator(\.punteggio, order: .reverse)])

Comment: @Marcy oh duh, I thought you said ".reverse()`. I totally misread that. What you said is exactly what i had in mind

Comment: hi @Alexander - the OP is perfectly correct.  With the exact code he showed you get *no result*, exactly at the OP said.  This would be very obvious to anyone expert, in, the topic the OP is asking about.  I suggest you delete your comment, as it's slightly rude to a new user, and totally incorrect.

Comment: (I refer to your first comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

You're just mixing up `.sort` and `.sorted`.

Use `.sorted` to make a NEW variable.

There's really no reason to use the low-level `KeyPathComparator` here, it's inappropriate. Just

```
let y = x.sorted{
    $0.title.caseInsensitiveCompare($1.title) == .orderedAscending
}
```

.. or whatever your fields are.  You can slso so this sort of thing

```
let y = x.sorted{
    someDictionary[$0.Code] ?? "" < someDictionary[$1.Code] ?? ""
}
```

another typical example when sorting tables

```
screen.dataSource.blah.sort(by: {
    $0[index].compare($1[index], options: [.numeric]) == which
})
```

The options like `.numeric` are very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this. It will sort your array in descending order of punteggio

```
squadre.sort(by: {$0.punteggio > $1.punteggio})
```

Comment: Almost. The raison d'etre of the question was that OP doesn't know about `.sorted`

Comment: What is OP @Fattie?

Comment: Wave! Just means, the person who asked the question. The "original poster".

Comment: I think if your answer had explicitly said that squadreSort is unnecessary and that it sorts in place then maybe this answer wouldn't have been downvoted.